# tsql distinct count subquery

Tags: t-sql, subquery, distinct

I am using SSMS 2008 and I need to use a subquery to return the count of unique records / client.  How do I do this?  Currently I am returning all unique records over the whole dataset and not per client.  Here is my pseudocode currently:

```
    SELECT A.Program, A.PEOPLE_ID, K.EVENT_NAME, A.Program2, A.Program3
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT K.EVENT_NAME) 
     FROM #TEMP1 A, evolv_cs.dbo.facility_view F, evolv_cs.dbo.people_x N, event_view K WITH (NOLOCK)
     WHERE F.group_profile_id = A.group_profile_id AND 
        K.event_definition_id = a.event_definition_id AND
        A.people_id = N.people_id
     GROUP BY K.EVENT_NAME) as DistinctEvent
     FROM #TEMP1 A
     JOIN event_view K WITH (NOLOCK) on K.event_definition_id = A.event_definition_id
     WHERE @START_DATE BETWEEN A.Enrolled_Date AND DATEADD(D, 14, A.Enrolled_Date)
     AND (@SERVICE IS NULL OR @SERVICE = K.event_name)
 GROUP BY 
A.Program, A.PEOPLE_ID, K.EVENT_NAME, A.Program2, A.Program3
```

OK, I edited the above query now.  I still want event_name per client.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, in this query you want to output the count of distinct EVENT_NAME values corresponding to each distinct combination of A.Program, A.PEOPLE_ID, A.Program2, and A.Program3?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use here is the [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause for your distinct counts, instead of the joined subqueries. The following two queries should give you what you want.

```
SELECT A.PEOPLE_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT K.EVENT_NAME)
   FROM #TEMP1 A, event_view K WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE K.event_definition_id = a.event_definition_id
         AND @START_DATE BETWEEN A.Enrolled_Date AND DATEADD(D, 14, A.Enrolled_Date)
         AND (@SERVICE IS NULL OR @SERVICE = K.event_name)
   GROUP BY A.PEOPLE_ID

SELECT K.EVENT_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT A.PEOPLE_ID)
   FROM #TEMP1 A, event_view K WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE K.event_definition_id = a.event_definition_id
         AND @START_DATE BETWEEN A.Enrolled_Date AND DATEADD(D, 14, A.Enrolled_Date)
         AND (@SERVICE IS NULL OR @SERVICE = K.event_name)
   GROUP BY K.EVENT_NAME
```

If you need to combine the results of the queries into a single result set, you should be able to do so with a UNION.

Comment: I like your solution, Brent, but I need to include many more fields in addition to these two distinct counts for this (single) result set.  How would I do that?

Comment: If those fields are aggregations (COUNT, MIN, MAX, etc.), then they can simply be added to the SELECT list. If they are at the same granularity as the grouping field (A.PEOPLEID, for example), then add them to the SELECT clause and also to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Could you give me more direction?  These additional fields are at same granularity as the grouping field.  But now I get the error:

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Update your post with the latest query.

Comment: I added a comment on the question for a clarification.